# Linear Approximation help

Tags: calculus

I need some help with the following problem. I know how to do a linear approximation, but in here they defined a function as another which throws me off. Can anyone point me in the right direction [image]

[image]

I'm thinking the following. A linear approximation takes the form of $y-y_1=f'(x)(x-x_1)$

so after I derive $g(x)$ I get $-4/(f(x)^3)$ times $f'(x)$ and if I replace $x$ for $-1$ I get

$\dfrac{-7}{16}$ which should be the slope but I'm lost here as I don't see my second point $(x_1,y_1)$. Please lmk

Comment: Plug $x = -1$ into the equation for $g(x)$ to get your $(x_{1},y_{1})$.

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you I ended up doing that and got y = -7/16x + 9/16. So I was on the right track correct?

Comment: Careful, double check your simplification.  It should come out to $y = -\frac{7}{16}x - \frac{5}{16}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear approximation you seek can take the form
$$
g(x) \approx g(-1) + g'(-1)(x+1)
$$

Now, you can get both $g(-1)$ and $g(-1)$ from the table:
$$
g(-1)=\frac{2}{f(-1)^2}= \frac{2}{(-4)^2} = \frac 18
$$

$$
g'(-1) = -4 f'(-1) f(-1)^{-3}=\frac{-4 \times (-7)}{(-4)^3}=-\frac{7}{16}
$$

and finally get
$$
g(x)\approx \frac 18 -\frac{7}{16}(x+1)
$$